Alert(message= str.tostring(timenow)) in Pinescript v5 doesn't show me the time properly
I am trying to add timenow for an alert to see the time when that alert was trigger but I have an issue to visualize it in alert log.
I tried this code:
if close>open or close<open
    // Define variables
    triggerTime = time
    
    
    // Construct the message
    message = "Alert triggered!\n" +
              "Trigger Time: " + str.tostring(triggerTime)
              

    // Send the alert with the constructed message
    alert(message)

and I see this:
timeout NOT working properly
but I want to see like this:
timeout is working properly

That’s a Unix timestamp. You just need to format it using str.format_time()

Thanks for help. I have another issue now, the time which is showing in alert log is with one hour less than my time zone. For ex. alert is triggered at 08:36 and my time zone is 09:36. Do you have any idea how to fix this?
